# nth-child in a WordPress loop?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to figure out how I can use nth-child to make every other instance of a div with the class "mask" change color. I have a template code that loops over and over on a page. Here it is:

```
<div class="view">  
     <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'clip-thumb' ); ?>  
     <div class="mask">  
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>  
        <p>Your Text</p>  
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
     </div>  
</div>
```

I want all the odd instances to be one color and all the even instances to be another. This was the code I was hoping would work:

```
.view .mask {
    width: 326px;
    height: 280px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}

.view .mask:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(235,167,32, 0.7);
}

.view .mask:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(4,141,195, 0.7);
}
```

What ends up happening, though, is that all of the masks turn one background color (the even color). This can be seen here: http://noellesnotes.com/portfolio/seventeen/

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of your `.mask` elements *are* even, in the scope of their parent (`.view`):

```
<!-- First Child (odd) -->
<div class="view">  
     <!-- First Child (odd) -->
     <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'clip-thumb' ); ?>  

     <!-- Second Child (even) -->
     <div class="mask">  
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>  
        <p>Your Text</p>  
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
     </div>  
</div> 

<!-- Second Child (even) -->
<div class="view">  
     <!-- First Child (odd) -->
     <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'clip-thumb' ); ?>  

     <!-- Second Child (even) -->
     <div class="mask">  
        <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>  
        <p>Your Text</p>  
        <a href="#" class="info">Read More</a>  
     </div>  
</div>
```

To achieve what you're after, change the following:

```
.view .mask:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: rgba(235,167,32, 0.7);
}

.view .mask:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: rgba(4,141,195, 0.7);
}
```

To:

```
.view:nth-child(odd) .mask {
    background-color: rgba(235,167,32, 0.7);
}

.view:nth-child(even) .mask {
    background-color: rgba(4,141,195, 0.7);
}
```

Comment: Great answer, @wolfemm. @Noelle, also note that because your `.clips` div contains other children besides `.view` divs, you might not get the exact results you want or expect either.  You might need to use nth-of-type(odd) and nth-of-type(even) instead of nth-child instead.